# How to use ProcessBuilder for running large-output programs in Java?

Tags: java, processbuilder, large-data

I'm trying to run fff.exe inside a java program.
- fff.exe algorithm:

```
$ run fff.exe ggg.txt 12345
while ggg has lines
    line = ggg.getline
    if line contains 12345:
        print.to.stdout( line )
```

- fff.exe reads ggg.txt line by line, outputting a subset of lines from ggg.txt;
- fff.exe's output is generated by a loop;
--- ie. one line at a time
--- ie. not generated all at once
- fff.exe's output is too large to be held in memory

When I run the following code inside main, the output is:

```
made it here
Done
```

and the destination file is empty; **what am I doing wrong?**  hhh.csv should be the output of fff.exe.

As well, **did I properly use ProcessBuilder?**  I mean to run fff.exe with arguments ggg.txt 12345 outputting to a file called hhh.csv.

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(
    "M:\\aaa\\bbb\\ccc\\ddd\\workspace\\fff.exe",
    "M:\\aaa\\bbb\\ccc\\ddd\\eee\\ggg.txt",
    "12345" );

try {
    System.out.println( "made it here!" );
    File destination = new File( "M:\\aaa\\bbb\\ccc\\ddd\\eee\\hhh.csv" );
    pb.redirectOutput( ProcessBuilder.Redirect.to( destination ) );
    Process p = pb.start();
    p.waitFor();
}

catch ( Exception e ) {
    System.out.println( e );
}

System.out.println( "Done" );
```

Comment: Possibly related to this bug? http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=8023130 Although it's going to be pretty hard to help you without knowing what fff.exe actually does. You might want to try to put together a simpler example that uses a basic command instead.

Comment: @Kevin Is the pseudo-code enough? post edited to reflect that

Comment: (For the record I didn't vote to close!) The problem is that I don't really see a problem with your Java code, except potentially the bug I linked to above. That means the problem is either in fff.exe or in the interaction between the two, which is really hard for us to debug. Something we could copy and paste would be best, because nothing is obviously wrong with what you posted.

Comment: fff.exe runs fine through cygwin, does that mean it is the bug?  I am not using code like that which is stated in the bug though...  could it be Eclipse perhaps?